# Updating many_to_many with put_assoc and an array of ids

Tags: elixir, ecto

I've got a simple schema Product with many_to_many :tags relation without an intermediate schema for the join table.

```
many_to_many :tags, Tag, join_through: "products_tags"
```

Now the question is quite simple, in Ruby's ActiveRecord, there's a convenient setter where you can just set to an array of IDs of the associated records, and it will automatically update the join records, ie.: `product.tag_ids = [1, 2, 5, 6]`.

In Ecto if I want to use `put_assoc`, it seems like it requires me to preload all the tags in a array, so I can `perform put_assoc(:tags, tags)`...

What if I don't want to preload them, like it's done in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1):

> What if I don't want to preload them, like it's done in ActiveRecord?

#### [`Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4) Docs (excerpt):

> When **updating** the data, this function requires the association to have been preloaded in the changeset struct. Missing data will invoke the `:on_replace` behaviour defined on the association.
>   **Preloading is not necessary for newly built structs.**

If you want to do it without preloading, I think you'll just have to write the query yourself.